# String Copy Internals

Tags: delphi, copy, deep-copy

Consider this code:

```
program Project11;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

function Test: string;
var
   r, s: string;
begin
   r := 'Hello';
   Writeln(Format('%.8x', [NativeInt(Pointer(r))]));
   s := r;
   Writeln(Format('%.8x', [NativeInt(Pointer(s))]));
   Result := r;
   Writeln(Format('%.8x', [NativeInt(Pointer(Result))]));
end;

var
  S1: string;

begin
  try
    S1:= Test;
    Writeln(Format('%.8x', [NativeInt(Pointer(S1))]));
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

When running it on Delphi XE I get

```
0040F358
0040F358
020A28CC
020A28CC
```

The question: why the compiler makes a deep copy when assigning a local string variable to the function's result?

Comment: Good question. Arnuad's answer at the dupe is excellent. It would be really great if somebody could cast the final delete vote on the erroneous accepted answer there.....

Comment: Well it turns out that the reason is the string literal used in the function's code; no literal, no deep copy.

Comment: Which is what Arnaud said